# Bash: How to check if first character of a file is {

Tags: bash, awk, grep

If the file is in the variable `filename`, what are some of the ways to do a simple check in Bash to determine if the first character of *the contents of the file* is an `{`?

It would be great if there is a way to do this without loading the whole file...

Ta!

```
#!/bin/bash
if #SOME_TEST "${filename}" then
  echo "yes, first char of file is {"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell-builtin command `read` can be used to read from a file; `-n1` tells it to stop at one character (whereas otherwise, it will by default read the entire first line):

```
if read -n1 char <"$filename"; [[ $char = "{" ]]; then
  echo "$filename starts with {"
else
  echo "$filename does not start with {"
fi
```

Comment: Might as well change `;` to `&&` in case the file's empty or unreadable.

Comment: The `;` is intentional and necessary. Remember, the record delimiter needs to be seen for a zero exit status.

Answer (score 1):

With standard POSIX shell:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

IFS= read -r str _
if [ -n "$str" ] && [ -z "${str%%\{*}" ]; then
  echo "yes, first char of file is {"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

- `IFS= read -r str`: Read first line of file into `str` without splitting on the `IFS` delimiter.
- `[ -n "$str" ] && [ -z "${str%%\{*}" ]`: True when `str` is not an empty string and the variable expansion `"${str%%{*}"` is an empty string.
- `"${str%%{*}"`: Expand the `str` string by cutting everything `*` starting with a curly brace `{`, so that if `str` starts with `{` it will delete everything in it, resulting to an empty string.

Alternatively, a `case` statement, can be more readable as [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469748/bash-how-to-check-if-first-character-of-a-file-is/65470257#comment115749817_65470257) pointed out:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

IFS= read -r str
case $str in
  '{'*) echo 'yes, the first char is {' ;;
  *) echo 'no' ;;
esac
```

Comment: It might be more readable to use a `case` statement and not need the parameter expansion. (`case $str in "{"*) echo "yes, the first char is {";; *) echo "no";; esac`)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
{
  if(substr($0,1,1)=="{"){
     print "yes 1st line 1st char is {"
  }
  else{
     print "No, it does not start with {."
  }
  exit
}
' "$filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate ask approach:

```
 awk -v RS=" " 'NR==1 '{ if (substr($0,1,1) == "{") { print "true" } else { print "false" } exit }' file
```

Set the record separator to spaces and then process only the first record/word. Check the first character using substr against "{" and print true if it exists. Exit straight after.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `AWK` following way. Let `file.txt` be your file name then

```
awk '{print /^\{/?"yes":"no";exit}' file.txt
```

will print `yes` if `{` is first characters in your file, `no` otherwise after reading first line of file. Explanation: I use regular expression to check if line starts (`^`) with `{` (which needs to be escaped thus `\`) and print `yes` if it does, `no` otherwise. After processing first line I end processing using `exit`. Keep in mind it will print nothing if `file.txt` is empty.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*